# Can't trigger onclick event with jQuery from node-horseman

Tags: jquery, node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to loop through a set of elements and click on each one which doesn't contain a table, however I can't seem to get it working at all. I'm using [node-horseman](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman).

```
var SELECTOR = "li:not(:has(table)) h2";
horseman
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0")
    .open(url)
    .evaluate(function (selector) {
        var els = $(selector);
        $.each(els, function (el) {
            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            event.initMouseEvent("click",
                true, true,
                window, null,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false,
                0, null);
            el.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
    }, SELECTOR)
    .delay(2000)
    //then do other scraping stuff
```

HTML structure(can't post actual html)

```
<li>
<h2>
    <span class="someclass">TEXT</span>
</h2>
</li>
```

From the above HTML some of the elements may contain a table element within them, under the h2 element.
When I execute this it doesn't click on anything.

Comment: and the html that goes with this looks like?  also console.log() is awesome for letting you verify that certain logic is executing up to a point.

Comment: Variables are case sensitive. You'r declaring SELECTOR and passing selector.

Comment: change to SELECTOR doesn't make a difference  i can't post the html but i will update my question to reflect the structure of the html at least. i print off the html which i scrape afterwards, which shows none of the elements expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) passes the index of the item as the first argument and the value of the item as the second argument when iterating over [arrays](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback). You need to call `dispatchEvent` on the element and not on a `Number`.

Either like this:

```
var els = $(selector);
$.each(els, function (idx, el) {
    ...
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

or [this](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var els = $(selector);
els.each(function () {
    ...
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: If you still have problems, then you need to register to some of the available [events](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman#events) such as `consoleMessage`, `error`, `resourceError` and `resourceTimeout` to see if they give any clues as to what goes wrong.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, can you give an example of how to register available events please?

Comment: I've added an example for horseman in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-4_horsemanerrors-js)

Comment: Ok so the error response with this ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'r.apply'). Trace says there are errors with the js on the page i'm trying to scrape? Several errors point to the line number where the errors occur but this isn't something i can control.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Have you tried to upgrade or downgrade?

Comment: 1.9.19, the latest, any version which you recommend?

Comment: There is no 1.9.19 PhantomJS version. It's the npm package version which includes PhantomJS 1.9.8. You can try to use the phantomjs2 npm package to get PhantomJS 2.0.0, but you will probably have to uninstall the previous npm package.